# cannot ping in private network after changing IP

Tags: networking, ip, iptables, private-network

I have two devices in my private network. One computer has IP 10.42.0.1 the other has IP 10.42.0.173.

I can ping from one computer to another and vice-versa.

If I want to change IP from 10.42.0.173 to for example 10.42.0.43 by ifconfig:

```
ifconfig eth0 10.42.0.43 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 10.42.0.255
```

I can still have ping.

But when I want change it form 10.42.0.173 for example to 10.42.1.43 by

```
ifconfig eth0 10.42.1.43 netmask 255.255.0.0 broadcast 10.42.1.255
```

I can ping from 10.43.1.43 to 10.42.0.1 But I can't ping from the other side (from 10.42.0.1 to 10.42.1.43)

Maybe it's problem with routing table. But I don't know how can I set it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first device has an IP address of `10.42.0.1` most likely with a subnet mask of 24 bits (`255.255.255.0`). In order for it to see `10.42.1.255` without a gateway, you must set the subnet mask to 24 bits or less (`255.255.254.0` or less) on **both** machines

Comment: I set ifconfig eno1 10.42.0.1 netmask 255.255.0.0 broadcast 10.42.255.255 and ifconfig eth0 10.42.1.43 netmask 255.255.0.0 broadcast 10.42.255.255 but doesn't  ping in any way

Comment: Do not set broadcast manually and make sure, you have both interfaces up, i.e `ifconfig eno1 10.42.0.1 netmask 255.255.0.0 up` and `ifconfig eth0 10.42.1.43 netmask 255.255.0.0 up`, just to make sure, cycle them down-up. Depending on your distro you will also have easier (and less error prone) ways to configure the network: sysconfig, network-manager, /etc/network/interfaces, netplan, ...

Comment: Thank you , it was the 'down' and 'up' trouble. Unfortunately I use  Yocto, and I haven't got /etc/network/interfaces file

Answer (score 0):

Netmask error.

```
ifconfig eth0 10.42.0.43 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 10.42.0.255 
I can still have ping.
```

That is network 10.42.0
With 254 hosts starting at 10.42.0.1 and ending at 10.42.0.254.
**Broadcast is  10.42.0.255**

```
But when I want change it from 10.42.0.173 for example to 10.42.1.43 by
ifconfig eth0 10.42.1.43 netmask 255.255.0.0 broadcast 10.42.1.255
```

That is a completely different network. Broadcast is at 10.42.1.255
And 10.42.0.255 is just a regular host IP.

Please get both on the same LAN. With the same netmask.

Comment: Can you tell me how can I modify 10.42.0.1 network to ping 10.42.1.42?

Comment: If you want to use two separate networks make sure that they do not overlap, and add a route. So if 10.42.0.0/24 (that is netmask 255.255.255.0) and 10.42.1.0/24 (also netmask 255.255.255.0). And add a route. Our put both in the same subnet (and on the same physical network).

Answer (score 0):

Computer `10.42.1.43/255.255.0.0` thinks that the other is in its network of
`10.42.x.x/255.255.0.0`. It will assume that the other is at
`10.42.0.1/255.255.0.0` and so will happily launch the ping packet.

However, the other way around, for `10.42.0.1/255.255.255.0` the IP of
`10.42.1.43` is not in its network and it doesn't have any routing rule for
passing packets to `10.42.1.x`. Therefore the ping will fail as there
is no network route for it to take. In other words, `10.42.0.1`
doesn't know how to send a network packet to `10.42.1.x`.

A packet that is launched on the physical network will be received by
every connected device. Each device will check each packet to see if
it is addressed to it. Therefore the point is to launch the packet,
which will happen in the first case, but not in the second one.